# Can I run multiple instances of Dropbox at once?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dropbox

I have a Dropbox account for work and one for personal. Is it possible to run both at the same time, storing Dropbox contents in different folders? (i.e. `Dropbox/Work` and `Dropbox/Personal`, respectively)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I know that it's possible to run Dropbox from the command-line, but can multiple agents be run at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible. Here is a snippet from the gentoo dropbox init script:

```
 start() {
     ebegin "Starting dropbox..."
     for dbuser in ${DROPBOX_USERS}; do
         start-stop-daemon -b -o -N ${NICENESS} -c $dbuser -S -v -e HOME="/home/$dbuser" -x /home/$dbuser/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
     done
     eend $?
 }
```

In your case the commands you need to run would be

```
HOME="/home/user/.dropbox/work" /home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
HOME="/home/user/.dropbox/personal" /home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

be sure to link the ~/.dropbox/work/Dropbox folder created on the first run of each process to ~/Dropbox/Work or ~/Dropbox/Personal or change it using the script described in the [dropboxwiki](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment#Changing_the_dropbox_folder_location).

Comment: Do note that running a program with a different `$HOME` has interesting side-effects (ie: when you click "Open Dropbox Website," the new browser instance _also_ uses the new `$HOME`).